# How to resolve error of JSONParser()?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I am trying to read from a json file using java. This is what I have so far:

```
 import jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.util.Objects;

 public static void main (String[] args){
      JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); //Error : JSONParser() in  JSONParser cannot be applied to expected parameters ...        
        System.out.println("Reading JSON file ...");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("data.json"); // *file not found exception!
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(fileReader); //JSONParser cannot be applied to java.io.File.Reader
        String t1 = (String) json.get("time");
        System.out.println("Time: " + t1);
   }
```

I have the following errors in this section:

```
  Error:(14, 29) java: constructor JSONParser in class       jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser cannot be applied to given types;
 required: java.lang.String,jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global,boolean
 found: no arguments
 reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I have the file data.json in the directory but it cannot read it and giving me FileNotFoundException

I found the following lines:

```
  import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
  import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

it is giving me the following errors for these two as well:

```
Error:(2, 23) java: package org.json.simple does not exist
Error:(3, 30) java: package org.json.simple.parser does not exist
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 . How can I solve these errors?

Comment: Well, the first error is because you're trying to call a constructor that doesn't exist. I'm extremely surprised that you're making a basic mistake like that, when the rest of the question doesn't imply that you're a beginner.

Comment: I am a beginner in Java. So how could I solve this problem?

Comment: I am following this code: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-read-write-json-string-to-file.html

Comment: Well you'll note that the tutorial has different imports than you have. Programming requires you to be careful, even (or especially) with powerful tools like IDEA.

Comment: Are you using maven to download the dependencies like that article says?

Comment: @Kayaman I have added those imports and it is giving me errors that I showed in the last part.

Comment: Since it seems that the tutorial has no mistakes, the errors are due to you not following the tutorial correctly. You can understand why that makes this a frustrating question to answer properly.

Answer (score 3):

`import jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser` This parser is not the one you're looking for.
The tutorial uses `import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;`, which requires that you add the proper packages by either adding this dependency to your Maven project:

```
<groupid>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupid>
<artifactid> json-simple</artifactid>
<version>1.1</version>
```

Or by having the proper jar file, *json-simple-1.1.1.jar* in this tutorial.

Comment: Problem is with JSONParser constructor itself, params are wrong